# How to open Viewcontroller from Appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase to send a message to ios device, I debug, I have received **data payload** in Appdelegate in func

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
```

I want to do how to open different view controllers based on that data, which means that when I click on the message, I will go to the corresponding view controllers.
I used the code below in Appdelegate but failed

```
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserNotLoginViewController") as! UserNotLoginViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = otherVC;
```

Comment: check your otherVC object also the window object it should not be nil ! Wow you are calling the show VC code ?

Comment: If nil then app will be crash, but my app just does not open different Viewcontrollers

Comment: nil does not mean app will crash always !!

Answer (score 1):

when you recive notification in didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate then call the function to pushview to nextviewcontroller.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
  data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
        // background
        pushToPage(data: data)
    }
}

   func pushToPage(data:[AnyHashable : Any]){
     if  let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
      let window = appDelegate.window {
      let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",  bundle:nil)
      let nextViewController = 
         storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
       window.rootViewController = nextViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your way but still didn't open different Viewcontroller,
except the default Viewcontroller

Comment: when you tap on notification is this call didreceiveRemoteNotification delegate?

Comment: please check demo created on this link. i have made use of local notification. click on the button to receive notification. once the notification is received remove the app from background. tap on notification. it will go to designated screen -https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HJRcfmytWJKuHbDt4ko-RPmWYaSysNcr

Answer (score 0):

Declare this function in your appDelegate and then use it to change rootViewController.

```
 public func makeRootVC(vcName : String) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navigation.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigation
}
```

usage:

```
self.makeRootVC("YourViewControllerStoryboardID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
func handlePushNotification(userInfo: [String: Any]) {

        guard let notificationType = userInfo["nt"] as? String else {
            return
        }

        if notificationType.toInt() == 1 {
            self.navigateToViewController1()
        } else if notificationType.toInt() == 2 {
            self.navigateToViewController2()
        }

    }
```

And for navigation, you can use this below function

```
fileprivate func navigateToViewController1() {
        if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

            if let _ = rootViewController.topViewController as? VC1 {
                let vc = AppStoryboard.Main.viewController(viewControllerClass: VC3.self)
                rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func navigateToViewController2() {

        if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

            if let homeVC = rootViewController.topViewController as? VC2 {
            }
        }
    }
```

Still, you face any issue so please let me know.